# How do you change the variable in a settings file from an external HTML form?

Tags: php, html, css, database, serialization

How do you change the variable in a settings file from an external HTML form?

So, I have a setup.html that will include all the forms. Then I have a settings.php which will save the settings and then impliment on the index.php.

How do I make so that I can update and SAVE the input from the setup.html to settings.php?

It's constructed this way:

```
$Color = "red";
$Name  = "Name";
```

etc...

I've looked everywhere and found nothing about saving the input, thanks.

Comment: If you need to be able to update your settings through the application, it's easier if you store them in a different format than PHP code.

Comment: Care to elaborate? :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to edit local files then you should consider sqlite, it comes bundled with PHP and can give you database functionality without the need to install a database.

[heres a tutorial that explains how to use it](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/courses/cs903/2013_02/using_sqlite3.html)

as well as the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php)

Essentially you have a file (possibly settings.db) that serves as a database. You then open up a "connection" to that file and issue regular SQL commands to read and write your data. Just make sure that you put this file outside of your webroot, otherwise visitors would be able to download it and see all your content.

Comment: Is it really not possible to use something simple like this? A html form which updates a variable in a settings file(php file) and saves it?